# Make Bootstrap Carousel navigation show only on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was using Bootstrap's Carousel, found [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel). It's a great script, unfortunately, I'd like for it to be able for the navigation arrows to go away and only appear on hover. Is this possible and how would I would go about implementing that?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You just need a little bit of CSS

```css
.carousel .carousel-control { visibility: hidden; }
.carousel:hover .carousel-control { visibility: visible; }
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/5Uxxx/)

Comment: Wow. Cool answer. I was thinking it had to be done with JQuery, but obviously not!

Comment: For Bootstrap 4: `.carousel .carousel-control-prev, .carousel .carousel-control-next`

Answer (score 2):

Its also nice to get rid of those pesky gradients, which adding this also does:

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  background: none !important;
  filter: progid: none !important;
  outline: 0;
}
.carousel .carousel-control {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.carousel:hover .carousel-control {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Comment: I found the information useful, although it is not an aswer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a follow-up to @Sherbrow's answer that works with Bootstrap 5. It also includes a fade-in and an animation of the arrows.

```
.carousel .carousel-control-prev,
.carousel .carousel-control-next
{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel-control-prev,
.carousel:hover .carousel-control-next
{
    visibility: visible;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel-control-prev
{
    animation-name: FadeInPrev;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel-control-next
{
    animation-name: FadeInNext;
}

@keyframes FadeInPrev
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 0;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }
    100%
    {
        opacity: 1;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
}

@keyframes FadeInNext
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 0;
        padding-right: 40px;
    }
    100%
    {
        opacity: 1;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
}
```